# how to verify the hashed password?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-password-hash

I am using CodeIgniter framework.
Below is the function contained in the Signup.php controller.

```
 public function _hash_string($str){
            $hashed_string = password_hash($str, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            return $hashed_string;
        }

        public function _verify_hash($text, $hashed_string){
            $result = password_verify($text, $hashed_string);
            return result; //TRUE OR FALSE
        }

        public function index()
        {
            if($this->input->post('newuser') == 1)
            {
                $user = new Users_model();
                $user->username = $this->input->post('username');
                $user->email = $this->input->post('email');
                $pass= $this->input->post('password');
                $hashed_pass = $this ->_hash_string($pass);
                $user->password = $hashed_pass;
                $user->account_status = 1;
                $user->user_role = $this->input->post('user_role');
                $id = $this->usermodel->insert($user);
}else{
            $this->load->view('signup-page');
        }
```

I've successfully hashed the user's password. How can I verify them?
Below is the function contained in the Login.php controller.

```
public function index()
    {
        if($this->input->post('login') == 1)
        {
            $user = new Users_model();
            $user->email = $this->input->post('email');
            $user->password = $this->input->post('password');
            $user->user_role = $this->input->post('user_role');
            $results = $this->usermodel->login($user);
            if(count($results) > 0)
            {
                foreach($results as $row)
                {
                    $session_array = array(
                        "id" => $row['id'],
                        "username" => $row['username'],
                        "email" => $row['email'],
                        "password" => $row['password'],
                        "account_status" => $row['account_status'],
                        "user_role" => $row['user_role']
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
                    $url = base_url() . "home?login=success"; 
                    redirect($url, "refresh"); 
                }
            }else{
                $url = base_url() . "login?login=failed"; 
                redirect($url, "refresh"); 
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login-page');
        }
    }
```

And here is the Users_model.php model.

```
function login($user){
        $conditions = array(
                    "email" => $user->email, 
                    "password" => $user->password,
                    "user_role" => $user->user_role,
                    "account_status" => 1,
                );
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where($conditions);
        $rs= $this->db->get();
        return $rs->result_array();
    }
```

What should I do to properly log the user in?

Comment: You've already written the function `_verify_hash` … so use that? What's the problem?

Comment: sorry, I didn't know where should I use that, inside the login.php controller or Users_model.php model?

Comment: @QiYang That is a design question. Up to you

Comment: @Ice76 can you show me?

Answer (score -1):

You can't compare password in mysql. because hashed using php, you have to use php function to compare password.

```
function login($user){
    $conditions = array(
                "email" => $user->email, 
                //"password" => $user->password,
                "user_role" => $user->user_role,
                "account_status" => 1,
            );
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where($conditions);
    $rs= $this->db->get();
    if(!empty($rs)) {
       $result_array = $rs->row_array();
       $controllerInstance = & get_instance(); 
if($controllerInstance->_verify_hash($user->password,$result_array['password']) == TRUE) {
        return $result_array;
      }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

use get instance to access controller. 
$controllerInstance = & get_instance();
$controllerData = $controllerInstance->_verify_hash();

Hope this helps. updated after zaph comment

Comment: Not encrypted, hashed.

Comment: @zaph how to verify my password?

Comment: When using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) verify with [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). See the examples in the links.

Comment: @Rajapandian what if I delete the _verify_hash function?

Comment: @Rajapandian  Message: Undefined index: password

Comment: sorry result_array will return associate array. Please use row_array.. 
Yes, you can remove verify hash and move it to lib or other file.